ImportError: DLL load failed while importing native_driver_python: The specified module could not be found
I have downloaded the TypeDB software on my Windows machine and tried to connect to TypeDB through Python to list all existing databases.
Before listing out databases through Python script, I have created a database instance in TypeDB manually using the TypeDB studio.
Wrote a simple python script to connect to TypeDB for test purpose. script as below:
from typedb.driver import TypeDB

with TypeDB.core_driver("localhost:1729") as driver:
    list_of_DBs = driver.databases.all()
    print(list_of_DBs)

Basically running this script should give me the list of databases that were created in TypeDB. But instead I came across the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\TypeDB_Data\conn_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typedb.driver import TypeDB, SessionType, TransactionType, TypeDBOptions, TypeDBCredential
  File "C:\TypeDB_Data.venv\Lib\site-packages\typedb\driver.py", line 24, in <module>
    from typedb.api.concept.concept import *  # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\TypeDB_Data.venv\Lib\site-packages\typedb\api\concept\concept.py", line 24, in <module>
    from typedb.common.exception import TypeDBDriverException, INVALID_CONCEPT_CASTING
  File "C:\TypeDB_Data.venv\Lib\site-packages\typedb\common\exception.py", line 22, in <module>
    from typedb.native_driver_wrapper import TypeDBDriverExceptionNative
  File "C:\TypeDB_Data.venv\Lib\site-packages\typedb\native_driver_wrapper.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import native_driver_python
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing native_driver_python: The specified module could not be found.

Can someone who have worked with TypeDB before please have a look here and help me out in resolving this issue?

The Visual C++ redistributable package was missing in my Windows OS. Installing the package resolved my issue.
